# Pull recent records from collection with group clause

Tags: magento-1.7, collection, sales-order, group

I am pulling records from `sales_flat_quote` using collection and to make the records unique i have applied `customer_email` `group` clause on collection. Below is the code.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', '1')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', array('notnull' => true));

$collection->getSelect()->group('customer_email');
```

here the problem is by using `group`, latest records are getting filter instead i want the older records to get filtered. guys please provide your valuable input on these question.

**EDIT** **[Explanation]**

lets say i am getting below records in collection and lets assume email address's column name is email

```
1. abc@abc.com
2. foo@bar.com
3. xyz@xyz.com
4. foo@bar.com
```

here when i do `$collection->getSelect()->group('email');` i will get filtered records as below

```
1. abc@abc.com
2. foo@bar.com
3. xyz@xyz.com
```

instead of that i want

```
1. abc@abc.com
3. xyz@xyz.com
4. foo@bar.com
```

Comment: What are those "latest records"?

Comment: latest records based on entity_id

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Tim please refer edit for explanation

Comment: You could potentially add an order by entity id DESC, but I'm not convinced it would work in every case?

Comment: @DouglasRadburn i had tried that also

Comment: do u want to order results first and then group by?

Comment: check this ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378049/sql-any-straightforward-way-to-order-results-first-then-group-by-another-colum

Comment: @huzefam yes i want in that manner order first and than group. for that i ordered the collection using `->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')` and than after that i groped using `$quoteCollection->getSelect()->group('customer_email')`, than also am getting same result.

Comment: print query and check what you are getting!

Comment: @huzefam you were right oder and than group did the trick, please check my answer below.

Comment: cool .answer seems fine :)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason it appears that that collection clears the `setOrders` when building the sql used. Maybe someone can shed some light onto that for you, sadly I cannot, but the follow code will allow you to do what you need without any expensive looping in php.

```
/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Collection $collection */
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', '1');

$collection->getSelect()->group('customer_email')->order('entity_id DESC');
```

Here we get the selection with the correct filter and then add the group by and order directly on the select object and not onto the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `->order()` to select should do the trick (if I understand your requirements right):

```
$quoteCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', '1')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', array('notnull' => true));

$quoteCollection->getSelect()->group('customer_email')
    ->order('customer_email');
```

This will produce the following query:

```
  SELECT `main_table`.* 
    FROM `sales_flat_quote` AS `main_table` 
   WHERE (is_active = '1') AND (customer_email IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY `customer_email`
ORDER BY `customer_email` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

**[My Solution]**

First fetch the collection along with order by

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_collection')->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC');
```

than apply group by

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('customer_email');
```

and after that add all the filters

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('is_active', '1');
```

**[END]**

can any one please clarify why below code dint worked.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/quote_collection')
               ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', '1')
               ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC');

$collection->getSelect()->group('customer_email');
```